# Covering number for the unit ball in a reproducing kernel Hilbert space

Tags: sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces, entropy, covering

I am looking for a reference for an upper bound on the covering number for the unit ball $\{ f \in \mathcal{H}: ||f||_{\mathcal{H}} || \leq 1\} $, where $\mathcal{H}$ is a reproducing kernel Hilbert space, the Sobolev space $\mathcal{W}^{p,2}([0,1])$ in my application. I have found some references such as

- Covering numbers of Gaussian reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces, T. Kuhn, Journal of Complexity,

but since this is solely for Gaussian kernels, it is not exactly what I need. Therefore I would appreciate all pointers. Thank you in advance.